# Is there any solution to error being recieved while loading jupyter-lab from cmd

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 20, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import aliases, flags, NotebookApp as ServerApp
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq_*init*_.py", line 50, in 
from zmq import backend
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_*init*_.py", line 27, in 
*ns = select_backend(first)
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init**.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\jupyter-lab.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 14, in 
from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server_*init**.py", line 4, in 
from .app import LabServerApp
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py", line 9, in 
from .server import ServerApp
File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 29, in 
from jupyter_server.extensions import (                             # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server.extensions

Comment: you should explain your question a bit more, I would suggest taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you have not installed some required modules e.g. jupyter_server.extensions and or setuptools. I guess you need to pip install them. Worth checking also whether you have more than one versions of python installed as this may cause issues some times.